# To count the number of occurence of a particular value in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown below

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
*         $       *
$         *       *
#         *       $
%         *       *
*         *       $
*         @       $
```

I want a sql query to count the number of stars(*) present in the table.

one option is to write the query in the following manner.

```
select ((select count(*) from star_table where col1='*') + 
(select count(*) from star_table where col2='*') +
(select count(*) from star_table where col3='*')) as count from dual.
```

I want to know if there is an alternative way of writing the query to get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(
             case when col1='*' then 1 else 0 end +
             case when col2='*' then 1 else 0 end +
             case when col3='*' then 1 else 0 end            
       ) 
from star_table;
```

**UPDATE**: If your columns contains on character length strings, you can:

```
select sum(3 - length(replace(col1||col2||col3,'*')))
from star_table;
```

You asked for this :)

Comment: This is faster than yours. A scan instead of three. However, I'll think about a smaller version.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT SUM(
    (CASE WHEN Col1='*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    (CASE WHEN Col2='*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    (CASE WHEN Col3='*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

[SQLFIDDLE MYSQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24671/2)

```
select sum(col1='*') + sum(col2='*') + sum(col3='*')
from yourtable
```

**For SQL Server here is:**

```
select sum(patindex('*',col1)) +
sum(patindex('*',col2)) +
sum(patindex('*',col3))
from stars
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE SQL SERVER DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6201/7)

Results:

```
| TOTALSTARS |
--------------
|         10 |
```

I have mistaken your sql developer to sql server till Florin pointed it out, here goes the **Oracle** version:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO ORACLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6201/9)

```
select sum(instr('*',col1)) +
sum(instr('*',col2)) +
sum(instr('*',col3)) as TotalStars
from stars
;
```

Results:

```
| TOTALSTARS |
--------------
|         10 |
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24671/3 check this out, seems the same results :) Can you tell the expected answer please?

Comment: again, this is Oracle not MySql. In oracle SQL you don't have booleans, what to say about adding booleans? :)

Comment: Oouch, yes it is.. it's MYSQL oh man. Sorry. @Florin then you got it mate :)

Comment: I'm working on sql developer, i get a error as "missing right paranthesis " for executing this query

Comment: Ur query seems simpler and good, But it is throwing error in sql developer.. Need help

Comment: @sathishkumar 
I updated with [`patindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) :) it gives the correct results, try please: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6201/6

Comment: This question is not on Sql Server. In Oracle would be something like `instr` function.

Comment: `sql developer` ? well then again. And I ended up writing an answer for three different RDBMSs ;) @Florin

Comment: @sathishkumar as you see the last edit is the Oracle version of the same query ;) Cheers. Nice question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
    select sum(decode(col1,'*',1,0)+decode(col2,'*',1,0)+decode(col3,'*',1,0)) 
    from tab;
```